# in C# assigning a array name to Json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have an Json array that looks like this:

```
[{"ticketAmount":5,"state":"Active"},{"ticketAmount":6,"state":"Closed"},{"ticketAmount":1,"state":"Resolve"}]
```

I want it to to get is an array that contains a assigned variable and then the Json, it should look like this(basically giving the array name):

```
"items":[{"ticketAmount":5,"state":"Active"},{"ticketAmount":6,"state":"Closed"},{"ticketAmount":1,"state":"Resolve"}]
```

My code:

```
public class EntityUserClosed
{
        public int ticketAmount { get; set; }
        public string loggedDate { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetUserClosedTickets()
{
    var entites = new List<EntityUserClosed>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select LoggedBy, count(ID) as ticketAmount from Tickets WHERE LoggedDate >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 30,0) AND State = '3' group by LoggedBy"))
        {
            var ticketAmount = 0;
            var loggedBy = string.Empty;

            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                     ticketAmount = (int)reader["ticketAmount"];
                     //Convert to JSON format
                     loggedBy = reader["LoggedBy"].ToString();

                     var entity = new EntityUserClosed
                            {
                                ticketAmount = ticketAmount,
                                loggedDate = loggedBy,
                            };
                     entites.Add(entity);
                 }
             }

             var json = serializer.Serialize(entites);
             this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
             var test = json.Replace("\\", "");
             this.Context.Response.Write(test);
         }
     }
}
```

I have tried a few solutions such as:

```
var entity = new List<EntityUserClosed>()
```

but not sure how that would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your serialization code as follows....

```
var json = serializer.Serialize(new {items=entites} );
```

BTW: `items:[...]` is not a valid json, it should be `{items:[...]}`